# remove hidden class from td in same row using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, webforms

I have records in table in webform with drop-down each row and hidden td. I want to show this hidden td if user choose certain value from drop down.

narrow down to my question; I want to remove hidden class from td, in same row and not effecting other hidden tds

### show this

```
<td class="answer unsatisfactoryGradeTab USGT1">
    <a href="#">Fill Form-H</a>
</td>
```

### Complete table

```
<tr class="tablerow">
    <td class="answer">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtClinicalProcedureElementID" runat="server" Visible="false" />
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ClinicalProcedure.Description")%>
    </td>
    <td class="answer">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtTeeth" runat="server" />
    </td>
    <td class="answer" id="tdGrade" runat="server" visible="false">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProcedureGrade" runat="server" />
    </td>

    <td class="answer unsatisfactoryGradeTab USGT1">
        <a href="#">Fill Form-H</a>
    </td>

    <td class="answer unsatisfactoryGradeTab USGT2">
        <a href="#">Form-H Completed</a>
    </td>

    <td class="answer" style="padding-left:10px">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lbnDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $("[id$='ddlProcedureGrade']")on("change",function(){
       if(your condition){
            $(".USGT1").removeClass(hidden class name)
        }
    });
```

Comment: it remove class from all the record not just from one record

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution;

```
 $(this).closest("td").next("td .USGT1").removeClass("HiddenField");
```